# CSS clip not working with absolute positioning

Tags: html, css

I am attempting to clip a photograph, but I want the photo to be in the same position as if it would be had I not clipped it. The problem is with CSS you need a position:absolute attribute in the css which then covers up data.

For example:

```
<html>
<head>
<style>
img {
    position: absolute;
    clip: rect(0px,60px,200px,0px);
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<img src="w3css.gif" width="100" height="140">
this is some text
</body>
</html>
```

This code covers up the "this is some text" text with the clipped image.

So I want a clipped image but the text not to be covered up.

Comment: `position: absolute` removes elements from the normal flow of the document. So they will overlap following elements.

Comment: Is there a way to crop images while still having normal flow of the document?

Comment: possible duplicate of [CSS Clip and Absolute Positioning](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1156776/css-clip-and-absolute-positioning)

Comment: Why not wrap the image in a relatively positioned DIV?

Answer (score 3):

It was because you had not given the `topoffset` value.

### [Demo](http://dabblet.com/gist/6df4268958ee3cdbc50f)

```
img {
    position: absolute;
    clip: rect(20px,60px,200px,0px);
}
```

#### Values:

> `clip: rect(top offset, visible width, visible height, left offset)`

1. The first number indicates the top offset - the top edge of the clipping window.
2. The last number indicates the left offset - the left edge of the clipping window.
3. The second number is the width of the clipping window plus the left offset(last number).
4. The third number is the height of the clipping window plus the top offset(first number).

Comment: I don't want the text to be on the image. I want the behavior to be as if you take out the 'position:absolute' and the picture will be to the left (cropped) and the text will be at the right, just like as if I didn't crop the image at all.

Comment: @Matthew - So from where you want to crop the image? left, right, top, bottom?

Comment: @Matthew - `clip` property only works if it is positioned `absolutely`.

Comment: @Matthew - Could you create an image showing exactly what you want?

Comment: I don't know how to upload an image on this, but imagine that on my webserver I have an image of a car. The actual image file is the full image of the vehicle from bumper to bumper. What I would like to do is have CSS crop the photo to only the door. I want the photo to remain in tact as a complete photo but just show the cropped photo. I want that cropped photo to behave as if it were its own photo.

Comment: @Matthew - Upload that image to [postimage](http://postimg.org/) and send me a link.

Comment: http://postimg.org/image/jw60n2ehx/

That w3 image should be clipped with the text next to the image.

Comment: @Matthew - What should be visible?

Comment: Just any clipped version of the w3 image.